# Which meaning do I have to pick up, deontic or epistemic, for ought to?

Tags: modal-verbs

> Oh,you may not think I'm pretty,
>
> But don't judge on what you see,
>
> I'll eat myself if you can find
>
> A smarter hat than me.
>
> You can keep your bowlers black,
>
> Your tops hats sleek and tall,
>
> For I'm the Hogwarts Sorting Hat
>
> And I can cap them all.
>
> There's nothing hidden in your head
>
> The Sorting Hat can't see,
>
> So try me on and I will tell you
>
> Where you ***ought to be***.
>
> (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

It’s not easy which meaning to take for *ought to be*: deontic or epistemic ([OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/ought) #1,2 respectively). Is it depends on reader’s view or Is there any clue to read in a certain way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context here is the key, since "Where you ought to be" on its own can be either ("You ought to be sacked for incompetence like that!" versus "I'll put this jar back in the cupboard, where it ought to be").

In this case, the "song" is about the Sorting Hat, who is proclaimed to be an entity that can judge someone's "house" at school when the hat is put on. The song here elevates the credentials of the Sorting Hat to an entity that is especially knowledgeable (there's nothing hidden in your head / the sorting hat can't see), and hence it is likely to make the *right* decision.

For this reason, this *ought* is deontic, since it means "I will tell you / where the right place for you to be is". If it were *epistemic*, it would mean "I will tell you / a place where you might be able to be" which does not match with the previous content of the song, which makes it clear that the Sorting Hat is not only extremely knowledgeable and is going to make a good decision, but he is also the *judge*, and since judgement are typically authoritative and final, "possibility" is too weak to fit here.